# Units caculation in the article don't match for reynolds numbers higher than 1

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, units, drag, aerodynamics

The [article](https://mse.redwoods.edu/darnold/math55/DEproj/sp09/NateCurrier/NateDiffeqProject.pdf) discusses the forces acting on a falling object in respect to the drag forces and reynolds numbers.
The article suggests for varying Reynolds numbers, the force of drag equation is written as such:

> $F[d] = kv^n$

So the forces acting on the object will be described by the function:

> $−mg − kv^n = ma$

When the solution of that DE will derive from the reynolds number.

k is the air resistance coefficiant, and its units are N/sec.

How do the units make sense for reynolds numbers greater than 1?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: If units bother you, you also have the option of non-dimensionalizing the equation.

Answer (score 3):

The units of k changes accordingly. When n changes, the whole relation between velocity and drag force changes, it would be logical that the proportionality constant changes. Knowing this, it could be useful to write k as $k_n$, but in the article it is probably assumed.